# Another way of saying "being judged"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, past-participles

What is another way of saying "being judged?"

The context is:

> 1. Being judged gave me an open mind about the different ways other cultures are judged and treated as well.
> 2. Being criticized gave me an open mind about the different ways other cultures are judged and treated as well.

Does my revision make sense?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is insufficient context about *the form of judgement served* to answer meaningfully.

Answer (score 2):

'Critiqued' might be better than 'criticized', because it doesn't have as negative a connotation.  It can be destructive or constructive.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on the context of what was being judged. Competition entries are judged in a straightforward way, but people can be judged quite differently.

> Everyone was looking at me, I felt I was being judged/I felt under
>   scrutiny/I felt under pressure to [perform well]

Answer (score 1):

Have you examined any synonyms for "judged"? Such as

evaluated,
appraised,
assessed,
gauged,
rated

or related words, like

examined,
eyed,
scrutinized,
inspected,
investigated,
reviewed,
surveyed

Answer (score 0):

1. weigh-scaled
2. audited
3. reviewed
4. questioned
5. subjected to scrutiny